# MySQL EXIT HANDLER is not catching all the errors?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My MySQL procedure looks like:

```
create procedure create_feed (_id int)
begin
    declare exit handler for sqlexception
    begin
        rollback;
        select false;
    end;

    start transaction;

    insert into t1(id)
    values (_id);

    insert into wrong_table_name (id, createdtime)
    values (
        _id,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );

    commit;
    select true;
end//
```

After I　called this procedure, the t1 table is updated, and the value 'true' is returned. The **wrong_table_name** does not exist at all. Why?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? What storage engine are you using for t1?

Comment: It is 5.1??, cannot remember the last numbers. And I am using the default value for storage engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use a function instead of a procedure if you want it to return a value. Another option is to use out parameters if you want your procedure to return one or more values.

Nonetheless, I am surprised by your results. If `wrong_table_name` does not exist, then that proc should return true. As for t1 being updated, that would happen if you are using a non-transactional storage engine like MyISAM, which ignores the rollback.

I tested your code in MySQL 5.5.8, and it worked properly for me. Namely, it always entered the exit handler when `wrong_table_name` did not exist.